# Best way to get user input for a menu-driven CLI in C

Tags: c

What's the best way to get user input in a C program where the choices are of a limited number?

Say for example the choices are:

A) Print the list.
B) Add 99 to the end of the list.
C) Delete all duplicates.
5) Reset 5 times.

Entering "A" and then Enter is OK.
Or, just a single keystroke would work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getchar()`, or `cgetc()`, depending on the platform

Answer (score 0):

I have used something simple like the following:

```
int intput()
{
    char input = 0;
    int ret_val = 0;

    read(0, &input, 1);

    switch(input) {
        case 'c':
            // Do c
            break;

        case 'p':
            // Do p
            break;

        case 'd':
            // Do d
            break;

        case 'q':
            quit = 1;
            break;

        case '?':
            PRINT(ENABLE, "c - connect\n");
            PRINT(ENABLE, "p - ping\n");
            PRINT(ENABLE, "d - disconnect\n");
            PRINT(ENABLE, "q - quit\n");
            PRINT(ENABLE, "? - this message\n");
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
switch(input)
```

use...

```
switch (toupper(input))
{
    case 'A':
```

This will allow the user to enter 'a' or 'A' and saves you having to check for upper and lower case.